# Effect sizes (eta-squared) with confidence intervals for linear models

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, effect-size

STATA has recently implemented effect size calculations for regression models in their postestimation procedures [measures of effect size in Stata 13](http://blog.stata.com/2013/09/05/measures-of-effect-size-in-stata-13/). It takes a regression or ANOVA object as input, and returns eta-squared or omega squared as well as their confidence intervals.

Is anyone aware of any such or similar implentation in R software, or how this could be achieved using the contents of lm or aov objects?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I have the same problem: I want to calculate CIs for eta sq. in an ANOVA with R.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your best bet is to use `MBESS` R package. For more details, please see the [package's home page](http://www3.nd.edu/~kkelley/site/MBESS.html), [this comprehensive JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v20/i08/paper) and the [package's home page on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MBESS).

In addition, consider package `bootES` for calculating *bootstrap effect sizes*: [package's CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bootES). [This relevant tutorial](http://osc.centerforopenscience.org/static/CIs_in_r.html) might also be helpful. Finally, I highly recommend [this excellent article](http://jpepsy.oxfordjournals.org/content/34/9/917.full), which not only provides *general guidelines* on calculating and interpreting effect sizes and confidence intervals, but also some *specific recommendations* for studies with different research designs.

Comment: Aleksandr, thanks for your suggestion. How would you go about obtaining eta-squared with confidence intervals using the package, papers and tutorials you mentioned?

Comment: @Tormod: You're welcome. I will try to come up with an example.

Comment: Could you come up with an example?

Comment: @Deleet: Sorry, I don't have time for this now (and not sure whether I have enough expertise as well). I suggest you to read the article and tutorial, linked above.

Comment: I have gone thru tons of these and various R packages too. The MBESS package produces wrong results I think since the CIs do not contain the point estimate when CI is <50%. If not, then it is using an odd approximation that doesn't work for low CIs.

Comment: @Deleet: Regarding questions about MBESS, the best option IMHO is to contact the author directly. The second best option is to ask a separate question on this site.

Comment: I have already done so.